# How to show html code from javascript var?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var div = $.get( "https://m.vk.com/");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
str = JSON.stringify(div);
window.alert(str);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code print me text: "readystate"..I need show full html code of website...
How can I do it?

Comment: You need to put HTML into the variable in the first place. A jqXHR object is not HTML. Try reading the documentation for `$.get` for examples of how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

`$.get` return a promise (it's asynchronous call), so you need:

```js
var promise = $.get( "https://m.vk.com/");
promise.then(html => {
  window.alert(html);
});
```

NOTE: In the recent version of jQuery (not sure from which version) promises are compatible with native Promise objects (type A promise specification), so they have `then` method even that the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) say otherwise.